# Rutas de imagenes y archivos no encontrada

Tags: php

Les comento que tengo un problema, algo que vengo lidiando con esto y no le encuentro la solucion por mas que hace tiempo lo estoy intentando. Quizas por favor puedan ayudarme... :(

Estoy haciendo un programa en PHP 7, HTML 5, CSS 3, uso XAMPP y trabajo en un entorno de Windows 10 (64 bits) de lo mas normal todo. Tengo permisos de aministrador y de hecho solo yo trabajo en mi computadora sin otro usuario mas que yo. Las carpetas hasta donde yo he revisado cuentan todas con permiso total de escritura, lectura, etc.

Me he encontrado que tengo unas imagenes en una carpeta que quiero mostrar en pantalla y no logro hacerlo. El programa esta dentro de la carpeta htdocs como es habitual.

Sucede que tengo las imagenes en una carpeta donde la ruta absoluta de una foto determinada es por ejemplo:

http://localhost/proyecto/public/fotos/clientes/imagen.png

Bueno, esa foto no puedo mostrarla, no puedo acceder a ella, sin embargo si la subo un nivel si puedo acceder a ella, quedandome:

http://localhost/proyecto/public/fotos/imagen.png

o sea la saque de la carpeta **clientes** y la subi un nivel en el arbol de directorios.

pero yo necesito por motivos de orden, operativos y demas que la ruta sea la primera que nombre. Ni hablar si hago mas niveles (unos o dos carpetas mas anidadas), menos se ve nada...

Asi lo mismo sucede con cualquier archivo que tenga en un par de carpetas de profundidad (anidadas, uno dentro de otra)

Lo mismo me pasa con archivos .js o .css que despues de un par de niveles de profundidad ya no puedo acceder a ellos.

Ejemplo: si tengo: http://localhost/proyecto/public/js/archivo.js

LO encuentra sin problemas...

Ahora si hiciera por ejemplo:
http://localhost/proyecto/public/js/micarpeta/archivo.js

NO LO encuentra por que agregue la carpeta **micarpeta** y meti ahi dentro el archivo archivo.js

Igualmente con la carpetas de CSS, etc. despues de un par de niveles mas adentro no encuentra los archivos que esten alli.

Que puede estar sucediendo y como lo soluciono? Desde ya muchas gracias y que Dios los bendiga.

PD: usando rutas relativas o absolutas obtengo los mismos resultados...

Comment: Hola, podrías probar creando una nueva carpeta dentro de htdocs y luego crear subcarpetas dentro de esa y comprobar si funciona. Puede que la carpeta del proyecto tenga ciertos problemas.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si pones la ruta absoluta de la imagen en el navegador? Si la imagen está ahí y no la muestra, probablemente tienes alguna restricción, tal vez por .htaccess o, como dice @MaikelYordan, tienes problemas con las carpetas del proyecto.

Comment: Hola Maikel, la carpeta proyecto nunca me ha dado problemas de ningun tipo. solo cuando anido varias carpetas como ahora, despues de un par de niveles ya es como que se pierde la ruta o no puedo acceder a esas "profundidades"

Comment: Hola Triby. Si pongo la ruta absoluta de la imagen en el navegador por ejemplo:
http://localhost/proyecto/public/fotos/clientes/imagen.png
me aparece la pagina de error 404. Si pongo la ruta de la imagen en el navegador de la forma C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\public\fotos\clientes\imagen.png 
la puedo ver perfectamente

Comment: Mi .htaccess es este:

RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

#personalizar errores de navegador
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/Proyecto/error/
ErrorDocument 403 http://localhost/Proyecto/error/
ErrorDocument 500 http://localhost/Proyecto/error/


#solo controlador
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/$ index.php?accion=$1 [S]

#dos parámetros
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/*$ index.php?accion=$1&ide=$2 [S]

#3 parámetros
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/.*$ index.php?accion=$1&ide=$2&ide2=$3 [L]

Comment: En lugar de poner el .htaccess como comentario, deberías editar la pregunta para agregarlo ahí mismo. Por otra parte, es muy mala idea realizar la misma pregunta en varias plataformas, principalmente por el respeto que merecen las personas que invierten su tiempo para tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: Ah perdon. Soy nuevo en esto y no sabia que habia una regla no escrita de que estaba prohibido publicar en varias plataformas una misma pregunta. Pense que si en algun foro no tenian forma de responderme quizas en otro si. Y mas cuando era algo que me urgia solucionar. En cuanto a editar, lo pense pero crei que quizas si lo ponia en el post principal eso pudiera ser motivo de que alguien se molestara porque modifique en lugar de ponerlo debajo como comentario. Mis disculpas! Saludos cordiales!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya esta resuelto. En realidad mi problema estaba en el .htaccess con las reglas de RewriteRule (para URL amigables). Lo que hice fue a cada regla RewriteRule agregarle previamente lo siguiente:

```html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

que me permite utilizar libremente los directorios y archivos sin por ello perjudicar el uso de URL amigables. Con eso se resolvio el problema. Por lo que doy por cerrado el tema. Infinitas gracias a todos por su tiempo y paciencia.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes el proyecto en la carpeta proyecto intenta ponerla la ruta de la Imagen así

public/fotos/clientes/imagen.png

Comment: Gracias por responder. Tampoco se ve nada